# func.apply with THIS applying to no object

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the following code passes `this` and `arguments` to `func.apply`.

I tried to play with the code to figure out what it is doing, searched on the internet, etc., but couldn't find anything about using `apply` this way.

```
 function work(a, b) {
     alert( a + b ); 
 }

 function spy(func) {
     function wrapper(...args) {
         wrapper.calls.push(args);
         return func.apply(this,arguments);
     }
     wrapper.calls = []
     return wrapper;
 }
 work = spy(work)
 work(1, 2); // 3
 work(4, 5); // 9
```

The following call returns the result of `wrapper`

```
work.apply(this,arguments(a,b))
```

The result of `spy` is the same as the above.
But what makes `this` and `arguments` do the right thing in wrapper? Because without the `this` it doesn't work and why when i declare

```
let work = spy(work)
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`work` is already declared here (function declaration). You can use `var` instead if you want to redeclare.

In this particular example, you are not using `this` inside `work` function. So it doesn't make a difference even if you invoke func like this `func(...args)` as below:

```
function work(a, b) {
 alert( a + b ); 
}

function spy(func) {
   function wrapper(...args) {
      wrapper.calls.push(args);
      console.log({ this: this });
      return func(...args);
   }
   wrapper.calls = []
   return wrapper;
 }
var work = spy(work)
work(1, 2);
work(4, 5);
```